# What is the responsibility of Symfony command?

Tags: php, symfony

Is a class *\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command* something like a controller?

Is a responsibility of the class *Command* only passing arguments and process a output or can it be model layer?

Thank you for your opinion.

Comment: It is a command. Mainly used for CLI, every x you `php bin/console x` is a command.

Comment: I know. I wonder the responsibility of the class Command. If single responsibility of the class is only passing arguments and creating a output (and logic is delegated into model layer) or if I can inject for example EntityManager and work with data here.

Comment: I would definitely delegate the logic to some service. That way the same can be used both from `Controller` and `Command` if need be...

Comment: Your command can extend ContainerAwareCommand so you have access to the DIC. http://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a "controller", but whereas that term in a Symfony context is used for handling HTTP requests and returning HTTP responses, a `Command` handles command-line input and output.

The same best practices apply as for other controllers, it is a good idea to keep Commands thin, and move the business logic to the Model layer.